# Having some issues with MySQL code trying to get data from who im following + my self

Tags: mysql, sql

So I am right now coding a twitter like news feed but the problem is that my own posts shows 4 times before the post (there is 4 entries in following I think thats why its showing my posts 4 time)

```
SELECT * 
FROM following AS f, posts AS p 
WHERE p.post_user_id = 1 OR 
      (f.follower_id = p.post_user_id AND f.user_id = 1) 
ORDER BY  `p`.`post_time` DESC
```

So this is my code at the moment. Though I think its wrong since it'll show my posts 4 times. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please add table structure, example data and expected output.

Comment: Do you really want the data from "following" as a result, or just use it in the query to find if the post should be shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like you really don't care about the fields in `following` and just want the posts, how about using a `LEFT JOIN`?;

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN following f ON f.follower_id=1 AND p.post_user_id = f.user_id
WHERE post_user_id=1 OR f.user_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY  `p`.`post_time` DESC
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6daa4/1).

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `OR` in your `JOIN` criteria, I believe you are receiving a `Cartesian Product` when `post_user_id = 1`.  Try something like this instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM following AS f
    JOIN posts AS p ON f.follower_id = p.post_user_id
WHERE p.post_user_id = 1 OR f.user_id = 1 
ORDER BY  p.post_time DESC
```